# Android unable to get recyclerview clicked item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment which has an EditText which when a particular string is inputted, a programmatically created  RecyclerView is displayed directly below the EditText. When the item is clicked, it is saved using SharedPreferences.But  I cannot access the item in the fragment.
Java Code:

HomePageFrag:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"textchanged",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              if(charSequence.toString().equals("Taxi"))
              {
                  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                  layoutParams1.setMargins(40,0,40,0);
                  recyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(getContext()));
                  layoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.srch_qry);
                  recyclerView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
                  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                  relativeLayout.addView(recyclerView);
                  recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View view) {
                          sharedPreferences=getContext().getSharedPreferences("Clck", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                          if(sharedPreferences.contains("Clck")) {
                              clicked_itm=sharedPreferences.getString("itm", null);
                              Log.e("Item",clicked_itm);
                              if(clicked_itm!=null){
                                  relativeLayout.removeView(recyclerView);
                              }
                          }

                      }
                  });
                  Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Taxi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              }
                else {
                  relativeLayout.removeView(recyclerView);
              }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

CustomListAdapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomListAdapter.Holder> {
    public String[] taxi_list={"Audi","Tavera","Chevrolet"};
    public Context context;
    public CustomListAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cstm_lst_lyt,parent,false);
        return new Holder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
    holder.taxi_text.setText(taxi_list[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return taxi_list.length;
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
         TextView taxi_text;
        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            taxi_text=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.taxi_txt);
            taxi_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.e("Clck","Yes");
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences("Clck",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("itm",taxi_text.getText().toString());
                    editor.commit();
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

XML:

cstm_lst_lyt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#40000000"
    android:id="@+id/lyt">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/taxi_txt"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Audi"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:gravity="center|start"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check `Log.e("Clck","Yes :: "+taxi_text.getText().toString());` what you are getting in log on click of TextView

Comment: I am getting the text,but I want the data in HomePageFrag.java

Comment: `recyclerView.setOnClickListener` what do you expect from that?

Comment: when the recyclerview is clicked

Comment: you click on the recyclerview's item, not on recyclerview itself

Comment: Ok.I want the clcked data in the fragment.How do I get that.I tried SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a listener in your CustomAdapter class and in this case the HomeFrag class will be the listener. Example:

1.In CustomAdapter you will create an interface which will be a listener:

```
public interface RowClickListener{
    void onRowClick(String whateverTextYouNeedToPassToHomeFrag);
}
```

2.In Custom Adapter constructor you will pass a listener object and you would place it in a field of that type:

```
public CustomAdapter(param,param...,RowClickListener listener){
   this.listener = listener;
}
```

3. In your Holder class in onClick you would call the onRowClick method of the listener:

   ```
   public void onClick(View view){
       String text;
       listener.onRowClick(text);
   }
   ```

4.And then in your HomeFrag class when you are creating the adapter you can pass an anonymous class in the constructor:

```
new CustomAdapter(arg,arg...,new CustomAdapter.RowClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onRowClick(String textYouNeed){
        //do something with text

}
```

4.b Or you can do HomeFrag implements CustomAdapter.RowClickListener and then just do:

```
new CustomAdapter(arg,arg...,this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't get the clicked data in the Fragment, I passed the EditText object in the constructor of CustomListAdapter and set the text of EditText in  the constructor of Holder Class.
HomePageFrag.java:

```
 recyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(getContext(),editText));
```

CustomListAdapter.java:

```
public CustomListAdapter(Context context,EditText editText){
this.editText=editText;
}
 public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
 taxi_text=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.taxi_txt);
            taxi_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
editText.setText(taxi_text.getText().toString());
}
```